# Porting CakePHP passwords to ZfcUser

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I'm in the process of porting an old CakePHP (1.3.13) application to ZF2. In the ZF2 application I'm using ZfcUser for authentication and registration. However the Cake application has an existing userbase with hashed passwords and I would like to import those passwords so not every user has to reset their password after the new application goes live.

I figured out how the passwords are hashed in the old app. It's a SHA1 hash of the password appended to a salt.
I implemented a custom authentication adapter that extends ZfcUser's Db adapter (ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\Db). This custom adapter has an encryption strategy as a member variable:

```
class CustomEncryptionStrategyAdapter extends Db
{
    /**
     * @var EncryptionStrategyInterface
     */
    protected $encryptionStrategy;

    public function __construct(EncryptionStrategyInterface $encryptionStrategy)
    {
        $this->encryptionStrategy = $encryptionStrategy;
    }
[...]
```

I override the authenticate method in CustomEncryptionStrategyAdapter:

```
public function authenticate(AuthEvent $e)
{
        [...]
        if ($this->getEncryptionStrategy()->encryptPassword($credential) != $userObject->getPassword())
        {
            // Password does not match
            $e->setCode(AuthenticationResult::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID)
            ->setMessages(array('Supplied credential is invalid.'));
            $this->setSatisfied(false);
            return false;
        }
        [...]
```

In my zfcuser.global config I added the custom adapter so it uses that adapter first and if it doesn't work falls back on the default adapter:

```
'auth_adapters' => array(
                            120 => 'RedevUser\Authentication\Adapter\CustomEncryptionStrategyAdapter', 
                            100 => 'ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\Db'
                        ),
```

In this scenario the custom authentication adapter is called first and if it fails it calls the default ZfcUser Db adapter. However even when the custom adapter authenticates successfully and sets this information in the AuthEvent object and in the session storage (setSatisfied(true)) still the Db adapter is being called and that of course fails.

If I disable the default Db adapter in the zfcuser.global config then it works fine with old user accounts. However this is not what I want, because I want newly registered users to use the default Bcrypt encryption. Any ideas why upon successful authentication in the first adapter it still continues to call the authenticate method in the second adapter? Or is this expected behavior of the ChainableAdapter interface?